# ThinkPad T14 Gen 3 Type 21CF BIOS/firmware issue with laptop lid close and suspend

Tags: 22.04, suspend, bios, firmware, lid

I recently bought a ThinkPad T14 Gen 3 Type 21CF. Here's a link to the Lenovo product page: [link](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-t-series-laptops/thinkpad-t14-gen-3-type-21cf-21cg)

Here's what I did:
I have Ubuntu 22.04 installed. I ran:

```
sudo fwupdmgr update
```

I did this because my work laptop, an X1 Carbon Gen 9 had an important BIOS/firmware update, so I figured I should update my personal laptop too. This turned out to be a mistake. The below describes new behavior after the update.

The laptop shows more than a dozen:

```
blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13)
```

On startup before the Ubuntu login screen is shown. After researching this further it seems to be due to something related to the BIOS/firmware update.

My user-facing symptom is that when the laptop goes into a suspend state, the screen will not turn back on about 80% of the time. This makes closing the lid almost guarantee the need for a reboot. There is a similar effect for the auto suspension of the laptop on battery. It is obvious when the laptop will not exit suspension mode because the power indicator lights next to the power button and on the back of the laptop screen (In the "i" of the ThinkPad logo) remain on and not flashing.

After I noticed this, I wiped my disk and reinstalled Ubuntu 22.04, in case it was some sort of OS issue. The behavior persists after a fresh reinstall.

To remedy this user-facing symptom should I downgrade my BIOS/firmware? What's the safest way to do that?
Is there something I can do within Ubuntu to remedy this issue? What are the troubleshooting steps?

Comment: I've posted this on the Lenovo Forums too: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-T400-T500-and-newer-T-series-Laptops/ThinkPad-T14-Gen-3-Type-21CF-BIOS-firmware-issue-with-laptop-lid-close-and-suspend/m-p/5206985

Answer (score 1):

The blacklist issue is benign - it's because there are some duplicate hashes and it doesn't have any impact on operation

For the wake issue - can you confirm which BIOS and EC you have updated to? Are there any messages in the journal kernel logs on reboot? (journalctl -k -b1) that give clues?

This platform has been linux certified (with Ubuntu 20.04; but that shouldn't really matter) so suspend should work well.

Mark

Comment: The UEFI BIOS version is 1.32. I'm not sure how to interpret the journalctl logs. There's a lot to sort through.

Comment: EC (Embedded Controller) version is 1.25

Comment: I've posted this on the Lenovo Forums too: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-T400-T500-and-newer-T-series-Laptops/ThinkPad-T14-Gen-3-Type-21CF-BIOS-firmware-issue-with-laptop-lid-close-and-suspend/m-p/5206985